# Can't see correct percentage in upload with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, progress-bar

I'm trying to use the angular upload library to upload a file and see the percentage of uploading. The method itself works well and the file can be uploaded on my server but when i try to see the percentage it shows me this

```
progress: 6% 
progress: 100%
```

or anyway it shows only the first percentage, in this case 6% but could be 40% or something else, and then directly 100%. This is the code

```
$scope.uploadFileFunction = function(file) {
    var uploadUrl = "url";
    var newJson;
    var json = [];
    json.push(newJson);

    var self = this;
    self.loading = true;

    var fd = new FormData();
    if (file != undefined && file != null) {
        fd.append('file', file);
    }
    fd.append('json', angular.toJson(json));

    Upload.http({
        url: uploadUrl,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        data: fd
    }).then(function (data, status) {
        self.loading = false;
        $scope.uploadError = false;
    }, function (resp) {
        self.loading = false;
        $scope.uploadError = true;

    }, function (evt) {
        $scope.upPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + $scope.upPercentage + '% ');
    });
};
```

is it normal? It happens also if i upload large files. This is the link to the library i'm using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: yes it normal.. the update you get is like after every few seconds and nto for each % of upload, so its absolutely fine

Comment: So, my question now is... How can i see the percentage, real percentage, during the upload? i mean for example:

5%
25%
56%
78%
90%
100%

?

Comment: its the real percentage, not fake one... try uploading files of bigger size (1GB) and you will see the difference,

Comment: Yes but when i upload the file (i've got other informations as you can see, a json), the percentage is 100% but the POST isn't finished yet.. So are you saying me that the file is already uploaded but the other informations not yet?

Comment: I tried also with an image with size over 70mb and it's the same

Comment: Add your percentage calculation code inside a `$timeout()`

Comment: Hmm @danial can you please show me what you mean?

Comment: `....then(..., ...,  function (evt) {$timeout(function() {
        $scope.upPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + $scope.upPercentage + '% ');
   }})`